Stop Foreground Service By javascript
I am writing an app which launches a foreground service to maintain a long-time task so that it will not be killed by OS. The app contains a html,css and javascript.
Here is my MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!foregroundServiceRunning()) 
        {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyForegroundService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
            {
                startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }

    display_html();
    Javascript_Android_Communication();
}

public void display_html()
{
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}


public void Javascript_Android_Communication()
{
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
}


public boolean foregroundServiceRunning()
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service: activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if(MyForegroundService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
Here is my Foreground Service
public class MyForegroundService extends Service
{
    @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        Log.e("Foreground Service", "Foreground Service is running...");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

    ).start();

    final String CHANNELID = "Foreground Service ID";
    NotificationChannel channel = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNELID, CHANNELID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    Notification.Builder notification = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNELID)
                .setContentText("Foreground Service is running...")
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service enabled")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }

    startForeground(1001, notification.build());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


private void stopForegroundService()
{
    Log.e("TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE", "Foreground service.");


    // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
    stopForeground(true);

    // Stop the foreground service.
    stopSelf();
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
Now, I want to do one more thing. I want to add one more function so that I can stop my Foreground Service as if a switch. My questions are:
1.) How do I stop my Foreground Service and where shall I put my script? I searched in google and try to write one (stopForegroundService()) but I am not sure if I am right.
2.) The stopForegroundService() is not intended to be trigger directly in Android. Instead, I want to trigger it in javascript.
// Some other codes......

function stop_foreground_service()
{
    app.Stop_Foreground_Service();

    return false;
}

// Some other codes......

To perform it, I add one more WebViewJavaScriptInterface java class:
public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface
{
    Context mContext;
    MyForegroundService; // With some problems

    WebViewJavaScriptInterface (Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void Stop_Foreground_Service()
    {
        stopForegroundService();
    }
}

How do I import stopForegroundService() from MyForegroundService into the WebViewJavaScriptInterface java class?
